# Should I ask for a raise at current company when I receive offer+promotion from another company?

Tags: job-offer, manager, promotion, raise, employer

I will start by providing some little context: I was interning as a developer at a company A while I was in last year of my college, one year back. Since it was still a pandemic in my country, the company was reluctant in rolling a full-time offer. It wasn't the best company in terms of work culture, I had only sticked there for such a long duration because my team had very talented people with whom I was enjoying a lot working with. In the end, I ended up joining another company B for my first full time offer as SDE.

So right now, 8 months later, my former manager from company A has contacted me that they have got fresh round of fundings and all and they are trying to correct the work environment and all and wants me back for a new project. The company seems to be ready to offer me the role of SDE-2. (Few discussions are left but my former manager has said it will be mostly formalities)

Of course I am attracted by the idea of a promotion but I am concerned about few things. I am currently very content at my current company but I do feel from time to time that I am a little underpaid. So I thought to have a discussion with my current Manager regarding the offer I have received and would like him to consider increasing my offer(don't want them to match but at least increase the offer so I don't feel like I missed a good opportunity).

Should I have this conversation because I don't want to harm my current relations at the company. I cannot ask for a promotion since they have different levels as compared to other companies and require at least 2 years for promotion.

I want help on how to start and guide the conversation with my manager to have a fruitful discussion. Would be happy to provide any other points. Advice on any other aspect is also very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bargaining with a counter offer for a salary-raise can leave a sour taste with your current manager - especially after 8 months..

Comment: @iLuvLogix yes that's one of my main concern actually. I'm on a very good term with my manager, but at the moment I am very tempted by the promotion offer.

Comment: Conversations like these must have a clear and actionable objective. Do you have it here? It's not clear from your question how do you rate staying at your current company for X$ vs new company for Y$. Determine your preferences and only after act.

Comment: @nicola I felt the post is actually very long so didn't include pros and cons. I can include it if it helps but I actually wanted to know how to have this conversation with my manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does accepting an offer to stay with my current firm make sense?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54748/when-does-accepting-an-offer-to-stay-with-my-current-firm-make-sense)

Comment: see also: [Negotiating a pay rise with another job offer on the table](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35827/168)

Answer (score 7):

You definitely can and it is to your benefit to discuss raises with your current manager. **However, don't bring other offers into the discussion.** It has very low possibility to be taken positively. Most likely, it will be taken negatively.

If you want to approach your manager for a raise, the best way to start a discussion is by showing your achievements and value that you bring to the company.

As for the previous workplace, take into consideration all things that have made you leave previously. Salary increase is great, but it is definitely not everything.

Comment: I was thinking about bringing the other offer into discussion since it might increase the seriousness from his side, since he can stall the raise discussions to the next appraisal period which is at least 4-5 months from now. 

Salary increase is not the main thing I am looking into the new offer, but the opportunity to get a promotion in such a short time is what tempts me.

Comment: Bringing the other offer will probably do exactly the opposite of what you are hoping for. Do not mention that you are considering other options. It can go wrong many ways. For example, your manager might start to feel pressured or blackmailed to increase your salary. Or they might see it as a sign of disloyalty and loose interest in keeping you around.

Comment: I agree 100% with this.  Do not mention the other offer.  Your manager will think, 'what if there's a future offer from company C or D?  Will we be having this conversation about a raise, again?'  You don't want to cast yourself as someone who will demand a raise any time there's another opportunity floating about.